# Method to discover linear independence of binary code words

Tags: linear-algebra, binary

How to check in the easiest way possible the linear independence of these code words?

They are supposed to be linear independent, but I cannot find out why...

```
1st) 10101 00101 100
2nd) 00111 01100 101
3rd) 01001 10101 111
4th) 10011 01011 101
5th) 01100 11100 100
```

I've been told that, just by looking and the ones on each of them, I can discover quickly that they are linear independent, but how?

NB: There are similar questions but none of them address the down-to-earth method doable by a human to check linear independence, so, as far as I know, this is not duplicated

Comment: Looking at the next-to-last column, we see that number $3$ is not in the span of the other $4$.

Comment: @saulspatz, right, but is that enough to assert that the five of them are linear independent?

Comment: Not at all.  It's just to get you started.  Now you have to prove that $1,2,4,5$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, suppose you had a dependence, $$\sum_{i=1}^5a_i\vec {v_i}$$

We want to prove that all the $a_i$ are $0$.

Looking at the second to last column, we see that $a_3=0$.

Looking at the sixth column shows that $$a_3+a_5=0\implies a_5=0$$

Looking at the first column we see that $$a_1+a_4=0$$

Looking at the last column we see that $$a_2+a_4=0\implies a_2=a_1=-a_4$$

Looking at the third column tells us that $$a_1+a_2+a_5=0\implies a_1+a_2=0\implies a_1=a_2=-a_4=0$$ and we are done.

Comment: thank you very much